# error 500 if change framework version 3.5 and error 503 if framework 4.7 using plesk hosting godaddy

Tags: asp.net, frameworks, plesk, internal-server-error

i am having issue on having my default.aspx website using plesk godaddy hosting account.

if i change my asp.net setting framework to 3.5 error 503 shows up.
if i change my asp.net setting framework to 4.7 error 500 shows up.

i've tried to edit the web.config file to see what are the cause of error 500 but nothing displayed except this value "500 - Internal server error." Kinda lost here as have tried to google up an answer for this issue but none seems to be working.

Here are my web.config for reference. I'm clueless on which part is causing the issue.

```js
﻿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
 
 <system.webServer> 
  <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"/>
 </system.webServer> 
 
 <system.webServer>
  <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5.2" defaultLanguage="c#" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
 
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
    <trust level="Full" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.codedom>
    
  </system.codedom>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="eSPADA_dbConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=182.50.133.111;Integrated Security=False;User ID=something.mdf;Password=something" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  
  </configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: A8FF6ED8-3AE9-4CCF-9985-790E124D5E4F-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue Solved.

I remove this line of code and works fine afterwards.

```js
<system.webServer>
  <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5.2" defaultLanguage="c#" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
```